# pipeline with $match not work as per expectation on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have tried to do somthing like this join and search. I'm trying to do a search with in side pipeline with `$match`, but the issue is that `$match` is not working.

it is not searching or join two collections.

```
SELECT * FROM `post`  
    Left JOIN postcat ON post.id=postcat.postid  
    Left JOIN catagory ON postcat.catid=catagory.id  
    WHERE 
    post_name LIKE '%a%' 
    OR post_data LIKE '%some data%' 
    OR tags LIKE '%some data%' 
        OR post_url LIKE '%some data%'
```

This is my collection info

Post

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d29bd7609f28633f38ccc13"), 
    "postname" : "this is some data", 
    "tags" : "Damita,Caro", 
    "postdata" : "Berry  Roseline Lira Cristy Hedi Clem Nerissa ", 
    "catagory" : [ { 
            "catagory_id" : [
                ObjectId("5d29bd7509f28633f38ccbfd") 
            ] 
        }, { 
            "catagory_id" : [
                ObjectId("5d29bd7509f28633f38ccbfd") 
            ] 
        } 
    ], 
    "createby" : "5d22f712fe481b2a9afda4aa" 
} ..........
```

category

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d29bc271a68fb333531f6a1"), 
    "catagory_name" : "Katharine", 
    "catagory_description" : "Katharine" 
}
```

The code i have tried so far:

```
var search_data  = "some data";
var search_limit = 10;
var search_skip  = 0;

db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $lookup: {
        let: {
            post_id: "$catagory.catagory_id" ,
            postname: "$postname",
            posturl: "$posturl" ,
            postdata: "$postdata" ,
            tags: "$tags"
        },
        from: 'catagories',
        pipeline: [                    
            {
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: ["$_id", "$$post_id"] }, 
                            {  
                                $or: [
                                    {"$$catagory_name": { $regex: new RegExp(search_data, 'i')}},
                                    {"$$postname": { $regex: `^${search_data}` } },
                                    {"$$posturl": { $regex: new RegExp(search_data, 'i') }},
                                    {"$$postdata": { $regex: new RegExp(search_data, 'i') }},
                                    {"$$tags": { $regex: new RegExp(search_data, 'i') }}  
                                ] 
                            }
                        ]       
                    }   
                }

            }
        ],
        as: "catagories_data"
    }
},         

{ $limit : search_limit },
{ $skip : search_skip },
{ $group : { _id : "$_id", postname: { $push: "$postname" }  } }
]).expla(function (err, data_post)
{ 
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data_post);
})
```

i have no idea how to fix it. any suggestion on it

Comment: Is your `category_id` an array of `ObjectId` or a simple `ObjectId`

Comment: category_id is an array of ObjectId

Comment: @Ravi Shankar Bharti  : Inside pipeline can we match for parent collection?

Comment: what do you mean by matching to parent collection?

Comment: if im match out side $lookup it is tack too much time, sime time 250 seconde